# QT 5.4, Unable to access Resource from code

Tags: c++, qt, qresource

I try to include style images of my app into a q-resource file.
When I include the file directly in the code, it work, but when i try to use QResource, it fail (do not load the file).

I have the resource file in the main directory:

```
AppFolder
  |- main.cpp
  |- darkstyle.qrc
  |- darkstyle
       |- WindowTitleBar.png
```

The following example print: 
failed1
failed2

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QResource>
#include <Qfile>
#include <QDebug>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    bool ok= QResource::registerResource("darkstyle.qrc");
    if (!ok) qDebug()<<"failed1";

    QFile file(":/darkstyle/WindowTitleBar.png");
    //QFile file("../AppFolder/darkstyle/WindowTitleBar.png"); //that work

    if(!file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)) qDebug()<<"failed2";
    else file.close();

    //return a.exec();
    return 0;
}
```

Note: Qt creator by default create binaries (.exe) in a top folder: ../build-AppFolder_Qt_5_4_1_MSVC2013_64bit-Debug/debug/AppFolder.exe
The execution root path seem to be: ../build-AppFolder_Qt_5_4_1_MSVC2013_64bit-Debug

I tried most of possible combinations with execution paths.

Note2: Some examples use a .rcc file format, I have none of these, but that could be a clue.

Summary:
How to access a QResource file from inside a QT app?

EDIT 1: Content of qrc file:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>darkstyle/WindowTitleBar.png</file>
        <file>darkstyle/WindowTitleButton.png</file>
        <file>darkstyle/WindowTitleButton1.png</file>
        <file>darkstyle/WindowTitleButton2.png</file>
        <file>darkstyle/WindowTitleButton3.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Comment: What is the content of `darkstyle.qrc`?

Comment: I added the content of the .qrc file in the question text (EDIT 1 section)

Comment: Have you tried call Q_INIT_RESOURCE(resources) or add qrc:// in the path?

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html

Comment: If you uncomment your working solution and alter a bit to `QFile file("darkstyle/WindowTitleBar.png");` will it work? It seems to me that the problem is not with resource file but with a working directory.

Comment: @GreenScape: no, as I said, the working directory is ../build....
But i tried to set the .qrc file with a absolute/relative correct path to all: the project folder, the exec folder and the top folder.

Comment: @danielfranca: using this macro result in "unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl qInitResources_darkstyle(void)"

The problem seem to be linked to MSVS I will downgrade to 2010, to see if that is the problem. As I just tried with G++ and it work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to an incompatibility of the given version of QT with MSVS2013.
The problem is solved by downloading another version of QT or visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

QResource::registerResource("darkstyle.qrc") registers the resource description. If you want to use resources dynamically like this you need to register the compiled resources themselves. Run rcc -binary darkstyle.qrc -o darkstyle.rcc and use QResource::registerResource("darkstyle.rcc")

Alternatively, compile the resources into your binary directly. Do do so, use RESOURCES += darkstyle.qrc in your .qrc, and leave out the QResource::registerResource.