# Switch between multiple .qrc files at runtime

Tags: qt, qml

I have several themes folders each containing a `.qrc` file:

```
redTheme/
           - File.qml
           - qml.qrc
blueTheme/
           - File.qml
           - qml.qrc
```

I am currently able to switch between these themes at compile time. This means I need to change my `import` statement to the theme I want to use.

I would like to know if I could do this in runtime. It would give much more flexibility to the user. Example : user clicks on a `Button` which triggers a `signal` and loads another theme (from `C++` or `QML`)

My first interrogation is : should I use `.qrc` files or [QML Modules](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-topic.html)?

The former loads its content after being called from `C++` whereas the latter compels me to use `import` statements.

This brings me to other questions:

1. Can I use several `.qrc` files?
2. If so, can I "unload" a `.qrc` file? Could be a stupid question as
   I'm not  fully aware of the Qt Resource System mechanisms.
3. How would I load another `.qrc` file? I would have my `main.qrc` file
   loading views and my `themes.qrc` files loading the custom `QML`
   objects.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can, but only by using external resource binaries:

`qrc`-files can be either compiled into the executable or as `.rcc`-file. Those rcc-files can be dynamically loaded. See [External Binary Resources](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html#external-binary-resources). These binary resources can be loaded using [`QResource::registerResource`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qresource.html#registerResource) and [`QResource::unregisterResource`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qresource.html#unregisterResource).

Example:

```
//Build the resources using:
rcc -binary redTheme/qml.qrc -o <build_dir>/themes/redTheme.rcc
rcc -binary blueTheme/qml.qrc -o <build_dir>/themes/blueTheme.rcc

//And in your code:
QResource::registerResource("./themes/redTheme.rcc");

//switching the resource:
QResource::unregisterResource("./themes/redTheme.rcc");
QResource::registerResource("./themes/blueTheme.rcc");
```

Using this mechanism, you can pack each of your themes in a `rcc`-file and load it depending on the users choice.

Note: You can actually have a "default theme" compiled directly into the application. As soon as you load the `rcc`-file, it will overwrite all files with same names. As long as all resources look the same (same file-structure), this will work fine. And as soon as you unload the `rcc`, Qt will switch back to the applications resources.

Comment: I am a bit skeptical about this working. Firstly, you haven't mentioned how the QML is reloaded by the QML engine. Secondly, how would the application know to load a different image when the new resource is registered? Have you tried this with, say, a simple QML application that displays an `Image`? Does the image get updated when the new .rcc file gets loaded?

Comment: I've set up your example and generated my `redTheme.rcc` file. I've placed it in the executable directory. However, when I use `QResource::registerResource("redTheme.rcc");`, it returns `false`. Why? Could it be because of my compiler ([see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29073163/qt-5-4-unable-to-access-resource-from-code))?. I'm also using MSVC 2013.

Comment: @Mitch your right, that won't update - switching the resources will not update anything, this has do be done manually, for exampleby restarting the app.

Comment: @GrégoireBorel - It works for me with MSVC 2013 - are you shure the path is correct? Try calling `File::exists("redTheme.rcc")` first to see if it is.

Comment: But then it's not really a runtime switch.

Comment: It is. Restarting the app is just one possibility. You could, for example, create a custom signal that all QML-elements can react to.

Comment: Okay my file is found (I had created a [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35870871/rcc-file-not-found-when-trying-to-call-registersource?noredirect=1#comment59420149_35870871) about this problem). However, as you guys anticipated, it won't update. I'm gonna try to find a way to update my QML elements without having to restart the app. If it works, I'll submit an edit to your answer.