# .rcc file not found when trying to call registerSource

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-resource

I have generated a `.rcc` file using the following command:

`rcc -binary redTheme/redTheme.qrc -o redTheme.rcc`

I then put the `redTheme.rcc` file into the binary folder. Finally, I register the file with `registerResource(const QString & rccFileName, const QString & mapRoot = QString())`:

```
QResource::registerResource("redTheme.rcc")
```

The method returns `false`. Do I need to set a path or something similar?

Note that I'm using `MSVC 2013` with `CMake`. According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29073163/qt-5-4-unable-to-access-resource-from-code), it could be a problem.

Comment: Does `QFile::exists("redTheme.rcc")` return `true`? If not, you might need to pass an absolute path.

Comment: I had tried an absolute path with backslashes but it didn't work. I switched to slashes and the file is now found.

Comment: Yeah, Qt always takes forward slashes in its API and does the native conversion internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to pass an absolute path. For example:

```
QResource::registerResource(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/redTheme.rcc");
```

One way to confirm this is to check if the following statement returns `true`:

```
QFile::exists("redTheme.rcc")
```